# What is a good set of notes to study human's eye mathematically?

Tags: vision, eyes, human-eye

I want to learn about the human eye. I could read a lot of online literature about it.

However, ideally I would like to study human's eye by solving some maths exercises. I suspect people have done this before. How would we have glasses otherwise?

Maybe you know good maths notes + PROBLEMS that would give me an insight into how an eye works?

The notes don't have to comprise a whole course. One chapter is enough, as long as there are some maths exercises attached.

Answer (score 2):

[Mathematical models of the human eye](http://www.dicca.unige.it/rrepetto/linked-files/gssi-course.pdf)

- Fluid mechanics

[Mathematics of Eye](http://prac.im.pwr.wroc.pl/~plociniczak/lib/exe/fetch.php?media=matokoang.pdf)

- Physics of blinking
- Thin layer approximation (lubrication theory)
- Aqueous flow in eye chambers
- Tonometry

Those two links provide quite a sufficient description of how to mathematically describe/analyze the human eye. It seems that you need to be fairly familiar with (at least) differential, integral and vector calculus in order to competently study the eye, mathematically. If you can get through (and understand) the fluid mechanics then you'll be well off.

And as for practice problems, aside from the examples in those links, I'm not sure you'll so easily be able to find sets of mathematical practice problems that specifically describe the eye. Or at least, I wasn't able to find any such  repository.